# How do I pass my id to the file SinglePost when I'm using on click navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Where the click happen:

```
<img onClick={() => {navigate("/single")}} className="postImages" src={post.img_url} alt={post.title} />
```

And here is the hole component:

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of code, type out the necessary portion. Also you'll need to clarify what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as a state (I assume `post` has an `id` field, feel free to change it if it's not):

```
<img
  onClick={() => navigate("/single", { state: { id: post.id } })}
  className="postImages"
  src={post.img_url}
  alt={post.title}
/>
```

And grab it in `SinglePost` with the help of `useLocation` from React Router Dom:

```js
// import the hook at the top of the component
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
```

```js
// use it inside the component
const { state } = useLocation();
console.log(state.id);
```